# Is it ok to have database context in my domain model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oop, architecture, onion-architecture

I am developing a web based application using ASP.NET MVC. I am trying have rich domain models rather than the thin/anemic models.

I have modelled my solution along the lines of Onion architecture. The different projects are as below :
[image]

- {}.Domain.Core - contains the domain objects and interfaces like IDbContext which is implemented in the Infrastructure layer
- {}.Database - is the database prject
- {].Infrastructure - contains implementation for logging, Data Access etc.
- {}.Web - View and Controllers

**** The data access is done using dapper and IDbContext is a wrapper around 2 simple command, query interfaces. I have isolated each of the queries as separate class.

For sake of discussion I am taking a small part of the application.

I have a versioned document library which contains documents along with other metadata like tags, permissions etc

A simplified model of my document object is as shown below

[image]

I would want the operations to be defined within the domain object, since there is business logic involved in each of these operations. 
Let me take "Delete" as an operation. The operation needs to be perform

- Validate if user has permission to delete
- Check if there are no associations which will get impacted by this delete
- Check if no workflow is in progress
- Delete the actual item from database in a transaction

As shown in above example, I would need the database context to complete this operation.
The way I have currently thinking if modeling is to have the domain object have IDbContext, which can execute the queries exposed.

[image]

In my controller class I call the domain objects and perform the operations.

I am not sure if passing the IDbContext in the domain object is ok? If not what are the better ways to model this?

I am not convinced in having a separate service layer because
    1) Controller act as first layer of service layer for most of the cases
    2) Service layer is just duplicating the same methods from domain to another class

Let me know how I can better this design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Injecting the `IDbContext` like that brakes the main principle of the Domain model which should be responsible for business logic ONLY while retrieving and storing your domain entities is the responsibility of the infrastructure layer. Yes you inject it by interface, hiding the actual implementation but it makes you domain model aware of some storage.

Also the steps from above required to delete a `Document` doesn't entierly belong to the Document object. Let's consider the first step with user permissions and the following cases:

- Users with Admin role should be allowed to delete any document
- Document owner should be allowed to delete the document

For the first case there might not be a connection between a user and a document to remove. Admin users are just allowed to do anything. It's like a classical example with two bank accounts and an operation to tranfer money which involves both accounts but is not their responsibility. This is when Domain services come into place. Please don't confuse them with Service layer services. Domain services are part of the domain model and responsible for business logic only.

So if I were you, I would create a new Domain service with `DeleteDocument` method. This should do the first three steps from above accepting `User` and `Document` as parameters. The fourth step should be done by your repository. Not sure what you mean by saying

> I didn’t see too much value in adding repositories

but from domain model perspective you already have one it's the `IDbContext`. I assume you meant some pattern to implement repository or separate repository for each entity. In the long run your pseudo code in the controller should be the following:

```
var user = bdContext<User>.SelectById(userId);
var document = bdContext<Document>.SelectById(docId);
var docService = new DocumentService();
docService.DeleteDocument(document, user);  //  Throw exception here if deletion is not allowed
bdContext<Document>.Delete(document);
```

If you expect you need this logic in many places of you application you can just wrap it up in a Service layer service.

I suggest reading Eric Evans [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215) on DDD if you want to learn more about Domain modeling. This discusses the meaning of entities, value objects, domain services, etc. in detail.

**ANSWER TO THE COMMENT:**
Not really, the domain services are part of the domain, so both implementation and interface are part of the domain as well. The fact that two or more objects have to interact with each other is not enough for creating a domain service. Let's consider a flight booking system as an example. You have a `Flight` entity with different properties such as `DepartureCity`, `ArrivalCity`. `Flight` entity should also have a reference to a list of seats. `Seat` could be a separate entity as well with such 
properties as `Class` (business, economy, etc.), `Type` (isle, row, middle), etc. So booking a seat requires interacting with different entites, such as `Flight` and `Seat` but we don't need a domain service here. As by nature `Seat` property makes no sense if not considered as a child object of a `Flight`. It's even very unlikely you would ever have a case to query a `Seat` entity from out of the `Flight` context. So reserving a `Seat` is responsibility of the `Flight` entity here and it's ok to place the reserving logic to the `Flight` class. Please note it's just an example to try and explain when we need to create domain services, a real system could be modeled completely another way. So just try following these three basic steps to decide whether or not you need a domain service:

> 1. The operation performed by the Service refers to a domain  concept which does not naturally belong to an Entity or Value  Object.
> 2. The operation performed refers to other objects in the domain.
> 3. The operation is stateless.

I'm accessing dbcontext from the controller which is application/service layer not domain/business layer. Domain model deals with business logic only, it should not be aware of any persistance logic and from the example above you can see that DocumentService has no references of the dbcontext.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. From what I understand, you are creating a domain service where one or more domain objects need to interact(which is true in most cases). In this layer you are accessing dbcontext. So the core domain is aware of the interface of domain service but actual implementation is outside? So my controllers still talk to domain and domain objects interact with domain services for performing any operation. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: thanks for clearing my understanding about domain service and application service. On a side note I had tried DDD by Eric Evans sometime back and gave up as I felt it was too dry. But with some real work to relate to, let me give it another try.

Comment: I see in you response that you are using 
- bdContext<User>.SelectById(userId);
- bdContext<Document>.SelectById(docId);
 
My confusion is, aren't these also operations which the domain objects needs to be responsible? 
for e.g. getDocumentByID might need to check if I really have access to that document.

one more thing, assuming in future I need to expose the operations to another system as an API layer for consumption (not via web but by normal assembly distribution), do you prefer to write a separate facade or the domain services should work as api ?

Comment: @Sharath Chandra yeah, DDD by Eric Evans is not an option when there's a work to be done now, try this shortened version though, it's only one hundred pages - https://ddd-cqrs-base-project.googlecode.com/files/DomainDrivenDesignQuicklyOnline.pdf

Comment: @Sharath Chandra  regarding your second question. Getting an object from a storage has nothing to do with business logic. This id has to come from somewhere: user checked an item on UI, there's a reference from another object, etc. So if you can't find it by id it is either a consistency bug, for exampe you removed an object but forgot to update other objects references or another user just removed it after it was displayed for you on UI which is common for web applications but still the issues are platform or storage related.

Comment: @Sharath Chandra  Though if you need to do some checks after you retrieved the object from your storage to make sure currect user has access to the object by checking some access list and/or roles this falls into business logic category and should be implemented within your domain model.

Comment: @Sharath Chandra  regarding the API question. It depends, usually I would prefer exposing only the functionaly third parties need nothing more and an API facade works just fine here. It greatly simplifies implementation and maintanance as for example when you want to make some changes to you domain model there's only a few entry points with a strict contrac for third party systems and it's easier to make sure nothing will go wrong if they update your system with a new version of your library.

Comment: @Sharath Chandra  But sometimes you don't have a choice and then you should be really carefull while modeling your domain. As third party systems can use all the functionality you expose via public methods both from domain services and entities. This means there are dozens of ways to use your library then and you have to be very carefull when making changes to it in the future .